# CSS :hover not working on touch devices - easy alternative?

Tags: css, responsive-design, hover, touch

I have a pure CSS menu which uses li:hover to display a drop down menu below the main navigation button.  Here is my menu...

```
<ul class="level-0" id="cssmw">
<li class="parent"><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a>
<ul class="level-1">
<li><a href="Page1Sub1.php">Page1Sub1</a></li>
<li><a href="Page1Sub2.php">Page1Sub2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="parent"><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a>
<ul class="level-1">
<li><a href="Page2Sub1.php">Page2Sub1</a></li>
<li><a href="Page2Sub2.php">Page2Sub2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

...and this is my CSS:

```
ul#cssmw {
cursor: default;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
}
ul#cssmw ul {
cursor: default;
font-size: 0;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
ul#cssmw ul li {
background-image: none;
float: none;
}
ul#cssmw li {
background-image: none;
float: left;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index: 100;
}
ul#cssmw li ul {
display: none;
top: 0;
}
ul#cssmw li:hover > ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
ul#cssmw li.hover > ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
ul#cssmw li.current > ul {
position: absolute;
}
ul#cssmw > li {
background-image: none;
}
ul#cssmw > li > a, ul#cssmw > li > a:link {
background-image: url("../cssmw_images/btn-mainnav-off.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
font-family: "myriad pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
height: 65px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
width: 130px;
outline-style: none;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
ul#cssmw > li > a:active, ul#cssmw > li > a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
outline-style: none;
}
ul#cssmw > li:hover > a, ul#cssmw > li:hover > a:link {
background-color: #FC9306;
background-image: url("../cssmw_images/btn-mainnav-on.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
outline-style: none;
}
ul#cssmw > li.hover > a, ul#cssmw > li.hover > a:link {
background-color: #FC9306;
background-image: url("../cssmw_images/btn-mainnav-on.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
outline-style: none;
}
ul#cssmw > li.current > a.current, ul#cssmw > li.current > a.current:link {
background-color: #FC9306;
background-image: url("../cssmw_images/btn-mainnav-on.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
outline-style: none;
}
ul#cssmw ul.level-1 {
left: 0px;
top: 100%;
}
ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li {
background-image: none;
}
ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li > a, ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li > a:link {
background-image: url("../cssmw_images/btn-mainnav-sub1off.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "myriad pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
height: 65px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
text-align: left;
padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
text-decoration: none;
width: 235px;
outline-style: none;
display: block;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 65px;
}
ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li > a:active, ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li > a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
outline-style: none;
}
ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li:hover > a, ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li:hover > a:link {
background-image: url("../cssmw_images/btn-mainnav-sub1on.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
outline-style: none;
}
ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li.hover > a, ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li.hover > a:link {
background-image: url("../cssmw_images/btn-mainnav-sub1on.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
outline-style: none;
}
ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li.current > a.current, ul#cssmw ul.level-1 > li.current > a.current:link {
background-image: url("../cssmw_images/btn-mainnav-sub1on.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
outline-style: none;
}
```

On touch screen devices there is obviously no "hover" state as the user either touches, or not, the initial button and if that button is, itself, a link to another page then it just jumps to that page and the user doesn't get to see the child menu.

Is there an easy fix to this?  I would like, ideally, on touch screen devices for the initial touch to display the drop down menu and, from there, for a second touch to trigger the link.

Would appreciate any advice that is offered.  Thank you.
NJ

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea but you must use a timer:
at first touch a timer will start and, for example, after 2 sec if the touch is already on, you will display the menu. P.S. sorry for my english!